# Outlook external API not available in CRM Outlook Client 2013 SP1 UR1

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, crm, outlook-addin, dynamics-crm-2013

We had part of code in JavaScript which was opening new window within CRM solution in Outlook. This part of code tries to open new window with features through external methods (available in Outlook).

```
function getOutlookHostedWindow() {
    if (!!window.external) {
        return window.external;
    }
    else {
        return window.top.external;
    }
}

function openStdWinWithFeatures(url, name, features) {

    var externalOutlookHost = getOutlookHostedWindow();
    var outlookWindowHost = null;

    if (!!(url)) {
        outlookWindowHost = externalOutlookHost.openWindow(url.toString(), name, features);
    }
    else {
        outlookWindowHost = externalOutlookHost.openWindow(null, name, features);
    }
    outlookWindowHost.opener = window.self;

    return outlookWindowHost;
}
```

This was working as expected on CRM Outlook client 2013, and CRM Outlook client 2013 SP1. However, after update to CRM Outlook client 2013 SP1 UR1, method `getOutlookHostedWindow()` returns object which doesn't contain method `openWindow()`. Actually when I debug this code, I see that both `window.external` and `window.top.external` don't have any methods on it.

This leads me to conclusion that method openWindow() from Outlook API was removed with new version of CRM client for Outlook 2013 (SP1/UR1).

Did anyone have similar issues, and is there any workarounds?
I was also unable to find corresponding documents which list methods available to windows.external for Outlook hosted apps.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Zec. Did you ever confirm your conclusion here? I am seeing a similar issue with the newest version of the CRM Outlook plugin.

Comment: Hi Tom - yes, I was confirmed by Microsoft support that this was dropped in the versions of CRM client for Outlook 2013(SP1/UR1). We had to code this feature using JQuery and other APIs.